# Drop duplicate in multiindex dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am looking to an efficient method to drop duplicate columns in a multiindex dataframe with Pandas.

My data :

```
TypePoint      TIME     Test   ...         T1      T1
-                 S    Unit1   ...       unit    unit
(POINT, -)                     ...                   
24001         90.00  100.000   ...     303.15  303.15
24002        390.00  101.000   ...     303.15  303.15
            ...      ...   ...        ...     ...
24801         10000  102.000   ...     303.15  303.15
24802         10500  103.000   ...     303.15  303.15
```

The header contain two information. The variable's name and its unit.
I would like to drop the variable "T1" (duplicate variable).

- **.drop_duplicates()** don't work. I get "Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)" error.
- **.drop(Data('T1','unit'),axis=1)** don't work either. That drop the two column and not just only one of them.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use double [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print df
  TypePoint   TIME  Test      T1        
          -      S Unit1    unit    unit
0     24001     90   100  303.15  303.15
1     24002    390   101  303.15  303.15
2     24801  10000   102  303.15  303.15
3     24802  10500   103  303.15  303.15

print df.T.drop_duplicates().T
  TypePoint   TIME  Test      T1
          -      S Unit1    unit
0     24001     90   100  303.15
1     24002    390   101  303.15
2     24801  10000   102  303.15
3     24802  10500   103  303.15
```