# Drop duplicate in multiindex dataframe in pandas based on column name

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Hi I have a problem follow up to my [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888189/drop-duplicate-in-multiindex-dataframe-in-pandas)
When I drop duplicate by index, the function doesn't verify that both my column name and my data are similar. Apparently it's based on the data.
For instance, if I have some data :

```
TypePoint      TIME     Test   ...         T1      T2      T3      T3
-                 S    Unit1   ...       unit    unit    unit    unit
(POINT, -)                     ...                   
24001         90.00  100.000   ...     303.15  303.15  303.15  303.15
24002        390.00  101.000   ...     303.15  303.15  303.15  303.15
            ...      ...   ...        ...     ...
24801         10000  102.000   ...     303.15  303.15  303.15  303.15
24802         10500  103.000   ...     303.15  303.15  303.15  303.15
```

If I realise this operation I will lose both T2 and T3 columns.

```
print df.T.drop_duplicates().T
  TypePoint   TIME  Test      T1      T2      T3
      -      S Unit1    unit        unit    unit
0     24001     90   100  303.15  303.15  303.15
1     24002    390   101  303.15  303.15  303.15
2     24801  10000   102  303.15  303.15  303.15
3     24802  10500   103  303.15  303.15  303.15
```

How to manage to drop duplicate based on both column name and data value ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think I was clear. I would like to drop duplicate based on both column name and data value. So to be more specific, I would like to keep the T1, T2 and T3 column even if the data are the same (because the column name are different)

Comment: That's true ! I will modify my exemple :p

Comment: I just modify the exemple ! :) Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thank ! I don't understand what set_index do there ><. If I understand well, you name the first level 'index' and the second level 'ndx' ?

Comment: I just did that so the columns would match up better with my starting data set.  You may not need or want to do that part.  Again, I can't exactly match the structure of your dataset but think the `reset_index()` step is the main thing you need b/c it changes the index to a column and hence means that the `drop_duplicates()` step will treat the column ('t1', 't2', etc.) names as data.